# Horizontal and vertical spacing in 'shaded*' environment using 'framed.sty' package

Tags: mdframed, framed

Using the `framed.sty` package to draw shaded boxes round text with the `shaded*` environment, there is only one parameter to set the spacing round the text. `\FrameSep` simultaneously adjusts both horizontal and vertical spacing of the text from the boundaries of the shaded box. Being awkward, putting `\FrameSep=1em` gives the left/right margins I want, while `\FrameSep=0.75em` gives the top/bottom spacing I want.

Is there a way of digging inside `framed.sty` to set left/right and top/bottom spacing independently?

If (as I suspect) the thing to do is to move to the much more flexible `mdframed.sty`, how does one produce a simple `shaded*` environment with that? -- I confess I'm finding the documentation hard to crack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\noindent Normal text here ...  
\begin{mdframed}[leftmargin=1cm,
    skipabove=1cm,    
    linecolor=blue,
    backgroundcolor=red!10,
    linewidth=2pt,
    innerleftmargin=1em,
    innerrightmargin=1em,
    innertopmargin=.75em,
    innerbottommargin=.75em,
]
If (as I suspect) the thing to do is to move to the much more flexible  mdframed.sty, how does one produce a simple shaded* environment with that? -- I confess I'm finding the documentation hard to crack.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

I don't think the documentation is any hard, see for example Page 6, where you can find most of the settings for adjustable lengths of `mdframed`:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the template to work from! I was probably having a senior moment ... ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `framed`: I redefined the `shaded*` environment to incorporate values for `\leftskip` and `rightskip`. Note it requires a blank line before the following text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{framed}
\renewenvironment{shaded*}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{shadecolor}}%
\MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}%
\leftskip 1.5em \rightskip 1.5em}%
{\endMakeFramed}%
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Gainsboro!60!MistyRose}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{H}{owever}, the egg only got larger and larger, and more and more human:
when she had come within a few yards of it, she saw that it had eyes
and a nose and mouth; and when she had come close to it, she saw clearly
that it was HUMPTY DUMPTY himself. ‘It can’t be anybody else!’ she said
to herself. ‘I’m as certain of it, as if his name were written all over
his face.’
\begin{shaded*}
  \lettrine{I}{t} might have been written a hundred times, easily, on that enormous
  face. Humpty Dumpty was sitting with his legs crossed, like a Turk, on
  the top of a high wall--such a narrow one that Alice quite wondered how
  he could keep his balance--and, as his eyes were steadily fixed in the
  opposite direction, and he didn’t take the least notice of her, she
  thought he must be a stuffed figure after all.

  ‘And how exactly like an egg he is!’ she said aloud, standing with her
  hands ready to catch him, for she was every moment expecting him to
  fall.

  ‘It’s VERY provoking,’ Humpty Dumpty said after a long silence, looking
  away from Alice as he spoke, ‘to be called an egg--VERY!’

  ‘I said you LOOKED like an egg, Sir,’ Alice gently explained. ‘And some
  eggs are very pretty, you know’ she added, hoping to turn her remark
  into a sort of a compliment.
\end{shaded*}

‘Some people,’ said Humpty Dumpty, looking away from her as usual, ‘have
no more sense than a baby!’


\end{document}
```

[image]